# How to pack transaction without cleos?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions, rpc, api

So the new API only accepts a packed_trx but there is no RPC call to pack a signed transaction.

How can it be done on system without cleos installed? Is there any implementation in pure Python, NodeJS or PHP?

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/OracleChain/chainkit/blob/master/chain/packedtransaction.cpp now trying to make use of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/OracleChain/chainkit/blob/master/chain/packedtransaction.cpp. This is my packtx.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "chain/packedtransaction.h"
#include <QDebug>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        std::string jsonString;
        jsonString = argv[1];

        SignedTransaction signedTx;

        QByteArray jsonByte = QByteArray(jsonString.c_str(), jsonString.length());

        QJsonParseError error;
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonByte, &error);
        QJsonObject jo = doc.object();

        if (jo.isEmpty()) {
           std::cout << "JSON object is empty." << std::endl;
           return false;
        }

        QJsonValue value = jo.value(QString("transaction"));

        signedTx.fromJson(value);

        PackedTransaction packedtx(signedTx, "none");
        QJsonValue packedJson = packedtx.toJson();

        QJsonDocument tmpdoc(packedJson.toObject());
        QString strJson(tmpdoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

        cout << strJson.toUtf8().constData() << endl;
}
```

You will need g++ with QT5 to compile it.

```
git clone https://github.com/OracleChain/chainkit
cd chainkit
rm test/main.cpp && rm utility/httpclient.cpp && rm utility/httpclient.h
vi packtx.cpp # copy&paste packtx.cpp source code
qmake -project
qmake chainkit.pro
make
```

Sample usage:

```
./chainkit '{"transaction":{"expiration": "2018-09-30T08:24:04","ref_block_num": 59970,"ref_block_prefix": 1935413997,"max_net_usage_words": 0,"max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,"delay_sec": 0,"context_free_actions": [],"actions": [{"account": "eosio.token","name": "transfer","authorization": [{"actor": "user2","permission":"active"}],"data":"00000000007115d600000000807115d601000000000000000447434e00000000046d656d6f"}],"transaction_extensions": []}}'
```

Sample output:

> {"compression":"none","packed_context_free_data":"00","packed_trx":"4288b05b42eaed125c73000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd0100000000007115d600000000a8ed32322500000000007115d600000000807115d601000000000000000447434e00000000046d656d6f00","signatures":[]}

Comment: I also had to edit the file chain/transactionheader.cpp:21 removing the + EXPIRATION_SEC as we are already giving the expiration as future date.

Answer (score 0):

RPC API could be helpful
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_info
For this is API, you need to forward an API point

Answer (score 0):

You can use eosjs to process transaction. here is link https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs